# Injecting an EJB into a JAX-RS 2 Resource (Jersey)

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, weblogic, ejb-3.0, jersey-2.0

I am trying to create a self contained web service with all the jersey dependencies included in the war for deployment to Weblogic. I would like to prefer the versions inside the war to the versions provided by default with Weblogic. I have the web service up and running but for some reason when injecting an EJB with `@EJB` into the JAX-RS Resource (a stateless EJB itself), the EJB is null.

Below is an example of how to reproduce this.

My pom dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

The web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
           <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>
                com.example.mavenscratchservice
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <jsp-descriptor>
        <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
        <debug>true</debug>
    </jsp-descriptor>
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</package-name>
            <package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.glassfish.hk2.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.jvnet.*</package-name>
            <package-name>jersey.repackaged.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>
        <prefer-application-resources>
            <resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.*</resource-name>
            <resource-name>META-INF/services/org.glassfish.jersey.internal.*</resource-name>
            <resource-name>META-INF/services/org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.*</resource-name>
            <resource-name>META-INF/services/org.glassfish.hk2.*</resource-name>
            <resource-name>META-INF/services/java.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</resource-name>
            <resource-name>META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.*</resource-name>
        </prefer-application-resources>
    </container-descriptor>
    <context-root>helloworld</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

JAX-RS Resource

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("rest")
@Stateless
public class ScratchResource
{

    @EJB
    private HelloWorldService helloWorldService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response helloWorld()
    {
        return Response.ok(helloWorldService.helloWorld()).build();
    }

}
```

The EJB

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class HelloWorldService
{

    public String helloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello world";
    }

}
```

And finally the stack trace I receive. I have tried changing the resource to a CDI bean and I have even tried referencing the EJB directly via it's JNDI using the lookup attribute of `@EJB`.

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.mavenscratchservice.ScratchResource.helloWorld(ScratchRe
ource.java:32)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl
java:57)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcce
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationH
ndlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMetho
Dispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMetho
Dispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatc
erProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.j
va:160)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMetho
Dispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(Resou
ceMethodInvoker.java:389)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(Resour
eMethodInvoker.java:347)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(Resour
eMethodInvoker.java:102)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:3
6)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(Reques
Scope.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java
305)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHan
ler.java:1154)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.j
va:473)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:
27)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContain
r.java:388)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContain
r.java:341)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContain
r.java:228)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.ru
(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.ru
(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecur
tyHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.ja
a:346)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.j
va:79)
        at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(Conver
ationPropagationFilter.java:62)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.j
va:79)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:137

        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:3
5)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformU
il.java:460)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.ja
a:120)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:
17)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:81)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.j
va:79)
        at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:2
0)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.j
va:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEvents
ilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.j
va:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationActi
n.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationActi
n.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(Authenticat
dSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java
120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java
57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebA
pServletContext.java:2285)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebApp
ervletContext.java:2201)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServlet
ontext.java:2179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.
ava:1572)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExe
utor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Comment: Which version of CDI? Do you have any beans.xml?

Comment: Which version of weblogic? Starting from Java ee 6 you do not need any web.xml.

Comment: Weblogic 12.1.3, I have a beans.xml in the WEB-INF

Comment: Did you try using @Inject instead of @EJB?

Comment: Yes I tried that also, still null

Comment: You're missing the jersey-server maven dependency?

Comment: That gets pulled in as a transitive dependency of jersey-container-servlet